# Failed to restart Apache2

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I get this error

```
/etc/init.d/apache2: 46: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
[....] Restarting apache2 (via systemctl): apache2.serviceJob for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl  status apache2.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.
 failed!
```

when i run

```
[apachectl configtest]
```

it shows
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: So does the file exist? Please check!

Comment: Have you removed /etc/apache2 or something similar, as it complains about multiple missing files?

Comment: when i ran [ systemctl status apache2.service]                           
 it shows        systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Answer (score 0):

apachectl told you that he can't open apache configuration file.

With help of the following command:

```
whoami
ls -la /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

check if file exists and file permissions.

In addition you could list and cat apache2 logs file in /var/logs/apache2

Comment: Both `/etc/apache2/envvars` and `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is missing according to the output. `envvars` is not typically something you change. It sounds like either a install interrupted in the middle, or a manual removal of config files.